# Power of Periodic Extension of a Sequence in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a sequence `x[n]` that is not zero only for `n = [1:3]`, while it is zero otherwise. I compute its energy as

```
Ex = sum(abs(x).^2)
```

and its power as

```
Px = Ex/length(n)
```

Now I have a sequence `y[n]` which is the periodic extension of `x[n]` with period `N = 7`. In that case, the energy of `y[n]` is

```
Ey = infinity
```

My question is the following: I compute its power as

```
Py = Ex/N
```

I am not sure if I am right about that. It confuses me that I cannot really define this sequence `y[n]` in Matlab due to its infinite length, as a periodic sequence, but I think I use the right formula.

If someone could give me some response on that, it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: There is a question on the DSP site very similar to yours: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16821/how-to-check-if-a-signal-is-power-signal-or-energy-signal . Take note of the formulas in the accepted answer. Does that answer your question? This question might also be useful: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77675/definition-of-power-signals-and-energy-signals

Comment: Thank you. Actually, my question is about the periodic extension of a sequence. While in the initial signal I calculate the power only over the interval where the sequence is non-zero (i.e., n=[1:3]), in its periodic counterpart I calculate it over a period (e.g., n = [1:7]), thus getting a smaller value. Intuitively, I feel that this is correct but still I am not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, the definition of signal energy and power are given in this slide:

[image]

As you can see, signal *energy* is just the total area under the squared signal, so the formula you used `E = sum(abs(x).^2)` is correct. Since signals that are periodic will have non-zero values for all time, the energy of a periodic signal is infinite.

However, signal *power* is defined as the limit of an integral. In the special case of periodic signals, this limit ends up being the area under the average squared signal for one period--in other words, the average energy for one period. In this special case, the formula `P = E_period/period_length` holds.
If a signal has a finite domain where it is non-zero, the power will be equal to be zero since the integral vanishes in the limit of large `T`.

The above properties naturally lead to two categories of signals:

- **energy signals** have a finite domain where the signal is nonzero. Therefore, they have finite energy and zero power.
- **power signals** have a finite power and infinite energy. All non-zero periodic signals are power signals.
- there is also "third" category of signals that have infinite energy and infinite power. `n.^2` is one example.

So to clarify, the power for `x[n]` is `Px = 0` since it is an energy signal, not `Px = Ex/length(n)` (that's power for periodic signals).

If `x[n]` is extended periodically forever in both directions, then it has infinite energy and power equal to  `P = Ex/length_of_period`.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for all the encouragement. I'm pretty sure half my reputation is because of you. ;)

Comment: @eigenchris - ahh... maybe 1/4 :) It's not all me!